# Master-detail chart with Navigator

Tags: highcharts, navigator

Can I use the Navigator from a Highstock chart in a Highcharts Master-Detail chart?

Comment: Can you please indicate what you have already tried? Or at least some snippet of the code you're starting with?

Answer (score 0):

To add Navigator it requires Highstock license. What is the purpose of using master detail chart with navigator? It's similar functionality. However, here is an example of this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/f7pmW/

Put in createDetail() function:

```
new Highcharts.StockChart(...);
```